# Does Jmeter/HttpClient ignore keepalive on "Retrieve All Embedded Resources"?

Tags: jmeter, httpclient

If you look at a normal browser - you will see multiple keepalive threads in your server-status on apache

The documentation for Jmeter shows that you can mimic this using "Retrieve All Embedded Resources", and setting a "Concurrent Pool" of say size 4 or 6. This has a similar effect and yes you will see multiple threads created to retrieve embedded resources, but HttpClient v3 and v4 both close down these connections after retrieving resources.

jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl

> 2015/12/15 13:56:16 DEBUG -
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection
>   0.0.0.0:50950<->localhost:80 closed  2015/12/15 13:56:16 DEBUG - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection
>   0.0.0.0:50951<->localhost:80 closed  2015/12/15 13:56:16 DEBUG - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection
>   0.0.0.0:50950<->localhost:80 closed  2015/12/15 13:56:16 DEBUG - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection
>   0.0.0.0:50951<->localhost:80 closed

The main thread will stay alive - but the resources threads will be closed.

Ive had a look at httpclient configuration settings, but none are preventing this. My current solution is to use the Java implementation(jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl)

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's a current limitation of JMeter HTTP Request with HTTPCLIENT.

You can open an enhancement request for it.